# How to get unit tests in Vue to stop going up the import hierarchy

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I'm just starting out with unit testing in Vue, and have already hit a roadblock on my first component.

This is my test:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import GeoframeLibrary from '@/views/GeoframeLibrary.vue';

describe('GeoframeLibrary', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(GeoframeLibrary);

  it('renders', () => {
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The problem is that `GeoframeLibrary.vue` imports a file, which imports another file, which imports my Vuex store init, and then:

```
 FAIL  tests/unit/GeoframeLibrary.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

       8 | import { AuthState } from './modules/auth';
       9 | 
    > 10 | Vue.use(Vuex);
         |     ^
      11 | 
      12 | const vuexPersist = new VuexPersistence({
      13 |   key: 'onspot',

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/index.ts:10:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/adonis-api/api-call.ts:7:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/adonis-api/auth.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/adonis-api/index.ts:1:1)
      at src/views/GeoframeLibrary.vue:55:1
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/views/GeoframeLibrary.vue:66:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/GeoframeLibrary.spec.ts:3:1)
```

Most of the Vue unit testing tutorials out there are overly simplistic and don't cover these real-world scenarios. I need my component to import other code to carry out specialized routines. How do I fix this and get my test to either *not* follow imports, or somehow just mock `Vue.use` to do absolutely nothing? Vuex is actually not part of my component at all, it just happens to show up in the error because it's being imported.

EDIT: It is indeed a strange edge case. Here's the reproduction repo:
https://github.com/ffxsam/repro-jest-importing

If you comment out line 17 in `src/adonis-api/crud-factory.ts`, the test runs fine. *Very* strange. Oh, and if you comment out line 8 in `src/adonis-api/api-call.ts`, it also fixes the test.

Comment: It seems odd to be initializing store from a component (instead of from main.js, where the main Vue instance is initialized). In any case, I tried to replicate that, but failed to reproduce the error. Do you have a more representative example? (e.g., GitHub link, or a codepen/codesandbox)

Comment: Can you add more info on how GeoframeLibrary.vue looks like.

Comment: Reproduction repo posted.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in the `vue-cli` repo. Their default `tsconfig.json` didn't have `"esModuleInterop": true` set. This apparently fixes it (for reasons beyond my comprehension).